# PHPmyadmin inaccessible on document root but accessible on any directory inside document root

Tags: phpmyadmin

On a *Ubuntu* 16.04.2 VPS I installed an *Apache2* server environment with `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ -y`. I then installed *PHPmyadmin* (PMA), as I always do:

```
cd /var/www/html 
wget https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.zip
find ./ -type f -name '*phpMyAdmin*.zip' -exec unzip {} \;
find ./ -type d -name 'phpMyAdmin-*' -exec mv {} phpmyadmin \;
```

Then, in my Browser, I did `VPS_IP/phpmyadmin` and got:

> This page isn’t working
>
> VPS_IP is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

- There are no errors in `auth.log` or `error.log`.
- There are no relevant warnings in *ctl*.

### When PMA does work:

PMA works if I move its dir into any dir inside document root, for example:

If I move `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin` **to** `/var/www/html/SOME_DIR/phpmyadmin`, I am indeed able to access it.

### My question:

what could went wrong so *PHPmyadmin* won't work when its dir located inside document root (but not in a dir inside document root)?

Comment: check in apache config for php and change the allowed host name form 127.0.0.1 to your IP

Comment: I get in from different PCs sometimes. I need it to be open for any IP, in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be associated with a malconfigured Varnish.

When I did `nano /etc/apache2/sites-available and changed`, changed 8080 to 80, saved and restart the apache2 service, the problem was solved.

I changed it to 8080 when I tried to install Varnish but I might have malconfigured it on the way.